# Message Log Component in C#

Tags: c#, .net, logging, components

What I want to have is a box that displays a list of messages in chronological order (most recent at the bottom) like is common in FTP apps and IDEs. Here's the FileZilla message log:

[Example of message log in FileZilla http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/9247/messageloginfilezilla.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/9247/messageloginfilezilla.png)

At the moment, I'm getting similar functionality from a read only text box, but this isn't perfect.

Bonus points for the following:

1. Context menu has the option of "copy this message"
2. Filtering by "level"
3. Option to write log to file

Comment: So, your question is "can anyone recommend such a component"?

Comment: why not use a list instead of a text box?  Though this answer used a text box initially:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196097/elegant-log-window-in-winforms-c

Comment: @Oded Yep, that's pretty much it. Not got my language head screwed on yet.

Comment: @SB Some great advice in that thread - thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could log [into Event Log](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/systeminformation/article.php/c12389). It has quite usable interface. You can also use [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) if you plan to switch to database, file or other logging destination which enterprise library supports

Comment: I might be missing something, but do they offer any way to view the logs? It's really the component I'm after.

Comment: Windows has a standard Event Viewer application you can view your logs with - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer

Comment: I eventually used this in conjunction with a ListView component.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in WPF made for log4net: [C# WPF Log4Net Viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/logviewer.aspx)

**Edit:**
Log2Console is an utility(winforms) based on ListView control for handling logs during development: [Log2Console - A Generic Log Viewer (for Log4Net, NLog...)](http://log2console.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Yeah, I'm opting for a ListView too for now.