# How to limit EventLog entries to one source?

Tags: c#, listview, event-log

I'm using EventLog to support a logging class in my C# application. ([Previously...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101594/message-log-component-in-c)) Here's a whittled down copy of that class:

```
class Logger
{
    private EventLog eventLog;
    private ListView listViewControl = null;
    private String logSource = "SSD1";

    public Logger(ListView _listViewControl = null, string _logFileName = null)
    {
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("SSD1"))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(logSource, "Application");
        eventLog = new EventLog();
        eventLog.Source = logSource;
        addListView(_listViewControl);
        logFilename = _logFileName;
    }

    public void addListView(ListView newListView)
    {
        if (eventLog.Entries.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (EventLogEntry entry in eventLog.Entries)
            {
                listViewControl.Items.Add(buildListItem(entry));
            }
        }
    }

    public void LogInformation(string message)
    {
        LogEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    private void LogEntry(string message, EventLogEntryType logType)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry(message, logType);
        if (listViewControl != null)
        {
            updateListView();
        }
    }

    private void updateListView()
    {
        listViewControl.Items.Add(buildListItem(eventLog.Entries[eventLog.Entries.Count-1]));
    }

    private ListViewItem buildListItem(EventLogEntry entry)
    {
        string[] eventArray = new string[3];
        eventArray[0] = entry.Message + " (" + entry.Source +")";
        eventArray[1] = entry.EntryType.ToString();
        eventArray[2] = entry.TimeGenerated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm:ss");
        return new ListViewItem(eventArray);
    }
```

The problem is, the ListView gets populated with the whole of the log - not just those from the specified source. Here's a screenshot of the output:

[Entries from all sources http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/6185/entriesfromalllogs.png](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/6185/entriesfromalllogs.png)

(In this image, the source of each entry is in brackets after the message.)

How do I get the EventLog to return *only* those entries from my source? Have I misunderstood EventLog completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EventLog.Source` member doesn't work as a filter.  According to the MSDN documentation for [`EventLog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)

> To read from a log, specify the Log
>   name and MachineName (server computer
>   name) for the EventLog. It is not
>   necessary to specify the Source, ***as a
>   source is required only for writing to
>   logs***. The Entries member is
>   automatically populated with the event
>   log's list of entries.

Because you do not specify a string for the `Log` member of the `EventLog` instance, it is getting everything.

Off the top of my head, there are a couple of ways to deal with this.

First, modify `buildListItem()` to filter on your source name.  This is relatively straightforward.

Second, create your own log.  Instead of logging to the `Application` log, create a log specifically for your application.  You can do this by altering your constructor:

```
public Logger(ListView _listViewControl = null, string _logFileName = null)   
{   
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists("SSD1"))   
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("SSD1", "TomWrightApplication");   
    eventLog = new EventLog("TomWrightApplication", ".", "SSD1");
    addListView(_listViewControl);   
    logFilename = _logFileName;   
}
```

All logging will now go to the `TomWrightApplication` log, not the generic `Application` log.

---

Tom, I've got a test project that simply does the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists("SSD1"))
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("SSD1", "SSDAppLog");
    EventLog log = new EventLog("SSDAppLog", ".", "SSD1");
    log.WriteEntry("this is a test");
}
```

This works successfully unless...the SSD1 source name is already registered with another log.  As I understand it, the source name must be unique across all event logs.  So, if you've already registered SSD1 with the Application log, the above code will fail when creating the new EventLog.  Try using the `EventLog.DeleteEventSource()` to remove the SSD1 source name from the Application log (just run this one time for your system).  The above code should work then (assuming you have admin privileges).

Comment: Hi Matt, whilst trying to use your second approach, I get the following error: "The event log 'SSDAppLog' on computer '.' does not exist." Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried reading from the event log so not sure how it works with filtering them, but a suggestion would be that instead of writing your events to the `Application` log you could create your own log create a new log called `SSD` or something and then when you write/read it it'll only be your events in there.