# WinForms or WPF control with a buffer to show constantly updating text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elegant Log Window in WinForms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196097/elegant-log-window-in-winforms-c-sharp)

I need a log-viewer to check the DB for new logs every few seconds and append them to a WinForms or WPF control. The control can have a buffer like command prompt and keep only the last [buffer size] lines.

What can I use for this?

Comment: @Surfbutler: Just saw it, it's for WinForms only though. What I need is a control that displays text and has a buffer for WinForms *or* WPF.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything that will do both, not for the visual parts anyway, the environments are too different.

Comment: @Surfbutler: I don't look for anything that will do both. I need WinForms **or** WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use WPF, then [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) control can work as display control. You can [define various templates using ItemTemplate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18561/Custom-ListBox-Layout-in-WPF) property of [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)(based on log type)

This ListBox can be bound to Observable collection of ViewModel/DataContext.

You can then define your business logic in viewmodel to add/ remove entries from ObservableCollection. Changes in ObservableCollection will get reflected in Xaml UI due to binding.

[Note - You can use any other itemscontrol, there is no compulsion of using [ListBox]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)