# Hightlight Listbox item on mouse over event

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am attempting to change a `listview` item's background colour when a mouse hovers over it

I have a mouse hover event, but how can I add a "highlight" effect upon a mouse hovering over the item?

```
private void pinnedAppsListBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: have you tried changing the background on mouse hover and changing it back to normal when mouse is out

Comment: @can poyrazoğlu Sorry I dont think I quite understand, could you elaborate / show example please?

Comment: Do you want to use a ListView or a ListBox?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this:

```
private void pinnedAppsListBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e){

   Point point = pinnedAppsListBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
   int index = pinnedAppsListBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
   if (index < 0) return;
   //Do any action with the item
   pinnedAppsListBox.GetItemRectangle(index).Inflate(1,2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the ListView's **ItemMouseHover** event and add then set the property "BackColor" of the Item.

```
private void listView1_ItemMouseHover(object sender, ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
            e.Item.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare this Global variable

Use this Listview Item variable to keep track of what item was hovered on

```
ListViewItem lvHoveredItem;
```

Set the following function to turn on DoubleBuffering for your control to prevent flickering:

```
public static void SetDoubleBuffering(System.Windows.Forms.Control control, bool value)
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo controlProperty = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control)
            .GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        controlProperty.SetValue(control, value, null);
    }
```

Where your control is loaded call this function

```
SetDoubleBuffering(lvTaskList, true);
```

Then use this code in the mousemove event of your listview

```
private void lvTaskList_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the Color you want the list Item to be when mouse is over
        Color oItemColor = Color.Lavender;
        Color oOriginalColor = Color.blue; //Your original color


        //get the Item the Mouse is currently hover
        ListViewItem lvCurrentItem = lvTaskList.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);


        if ((lvCurrentItem != null) && (lvCurrentItem != lvHoveredItem))
        {
            lvCurrentItem.BackColor = oItemColor;

            if(lvHoveredItem != null)
            {
                lvHoveredItem.BackColor = oOriginalColor ;                    
            }

            lvHoveredItem = lvCurrentItem;
            return;

        }


        if (lvCurrentItem == null)
        {
            if (lvHoveredItem != null)
            {
                lvHoveredItem.BackColor = oOriginalColor; 
            }
        }

    }
```

You can also add the MouseLeave Event

```
private void lvTaskList_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Color oOriginalColor = Color.Blue; //Your original color

        //When the mouse leave the control. If a ListViewItem was highlighted then set it's original color back
        if (lvHoveredItem != null)
        {
            lvHoveredItem.BackColor = oOriginalColor ;
        }

        lvHoveredItem = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a ListBox, it is quite more difficult to handle, you will need to set a MouseHover event for the ListBox and determine which item is being hovered on and then draw it manually.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192654/612717).

However if you're using a ListView, you can easily add an `ItemMouseHover` event like this:

```
private void pinnedAppsListView_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      e.Item.BackColor = Color.Lime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this question many times without a good answer.
There is no good answer that I know, but, I did it, using some hints elsewhere.
I did this using Lazarus, but you should be able to adapt it to your language.

Get the item. You may want to set variables to catch these individually.
You may also want to get the state of your mouse buttons at mousedown first.

```
If (ListView.GetItemAt(X,Y) <> nil) then  // do this with an if else

// Next, you can get the bounding rect:
ListView.GetItemAt(X,Y).DisplayRect(drSelectBounds);  

//Option: If Button up or down then 
// you may have to catch this elsewhere, such as for a drag operation.

// Create and set a boolean variable:
HighLightOn := True;
ListView.Repaint;  // clears previous hightlights
ListView.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace; // or your color of choice     
ListView.Canvas.FillRect(Rect); 

// If you are moving around in an area where GetItem is nil, 
// then do this to stop flicker and remove the highlight:

If (ListView.GetItemAt(X,Y) = nil)  // do this with an if else
If HighLightOn then
begin
    SelectedList.Repaint;
    HighLightOn := False;
end;

// If a highlight gets left behind, 
// you may need to repeat this elsewhere, such as in a component exit.

// This is the basic gist of the issue. 
// There can be a lot of options or things to look for, 
// so you code could get more complicated. 
// I am not suggesting this is the best way to implement it, 
// but it is easy. Part of this code only works inside your app!
```

Comment: The question is for ASP.NET not for VB.NET.   *There is no good answer that I know*  Good is second matter really...this one isn't relevant even!

Comment: The above isn't VB.net, I believe!