# How to change the background color of a ListBox Item when hovering?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

How do I change the Background Color of a ListBox Item when I hover over it?

I have overridden the DrawItem Event with this code:

```
private void DrawListBox(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();         
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ?
        new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(52, 146, 204)) : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
    g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
         new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

However, a ListBox does not have a Property which contains the hovered Item. There is also no Event like MouseEnterItem, MouseHoverItem Event, or anything similar on a ListBox to subscribe to.

I did quite a lot of research, but all I found was a similar question on SO, which confused ListBox and ListView: [Hightlight Listbox item on mouse over event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340135/hightlight-listbox-item-on-mouse-over-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the ListBox does not provide the MouseEnterItem and MouseHoverItem Events, it is necessary to code this functionality yourself, tracking the coordinates of the mouse to determine which item the mouse is over.

The following question is very similar, aimed at showing a tooltip for each item when hovered over.  Michael Lang's answer is a very good workaround and should be adaptable for your purposes:

[How can I set different Tooltip text for each item in a listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192584/how-can-i-set-different-tooltip-text-for-each-item-in-a-listbox)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want a **hover**? => user moves mouse and then **stops** over a point for a delay without moving again

If you want immediate feedback then use the MouseMove() event and get the Index of the item you are over with IndexFromPoint().  Store that value at form level so you can determine if it has changed since the last move and then set the background fill color accordingly in your DrawListBox() handler:

```
    private int prevIndex = -1;

    private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(listBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
        if (index != prevIndex)
        {
            prevIndex = index;
            listBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        prevIndex = -1;
        listBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void DrawListBox(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        Color c;
        if (e.Index == prevIndex )
        {
            c = Color.Yellow; // whatever the "highlight" color should be
        }
        else if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            c = Color.FromArgb(52, 146, 204); 
        }
        else
        {
            c = e.BackColor;
        }
        using (SolidBrush brsh = new SolidBrush(c))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(brsh, e.Bounds);
        }

        using (SolidBrush brsh = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
        {
            g.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font,
             brsh, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Comment: Flickers really badly.