# How can Hover highlighting in ListBox be turned off?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

After Win 10 update all ListBoxs in a project has Hover Highlighting turned on. It been a few days of searching for a solution with no luck. So far any Win 10 complications have been solved using ZAML.

Does anyone know how this is done?

VB.net 2017,
WPF,
Win 10

Thank you

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340135/hightlight-listbox-item-on-mouse-over-event

Comment: Hi,@Robert Cannistraci.Could you show the relevant code for your question? Have you set the style Trigger?