# What is this namespace ITypeOfObjectsBoundToListBox ? Couldn't find it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I took the answer to my problem from here:
What i want to do is to set different Tooltip text for each item in a listbox.

[ITypeOfObjectsBoundToListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192584/how-can-i-set-different-tooltip-text-for-each-item-in-a-listbox)

This is the method from the other answer in the link i'm trying to use:

```
private ITypeOfObjectsBoundToListBox DetermineHoveredItem()
        {
            Point screenPosition = ListBox.MousePosition;
            Point listBoxClientAreaPosition = listBox1.PointToClient(screenPosition);

            int hoveredIndex = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(listBoxClientAreaPosition);
            if (hoveredIndex != -1)
                return listBox1.Items[hoveredIndex] as ITypeOfObjectsBoundToListBox;
            else
                return null;
        }
```

But ITypeOfObjectsBoundToListBox is not exist.

Error: Error    2   The type or namespace name 'ITypeOfObjectsBoundToListBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is unclear with the error message? You need to reference an assembly in which the interface `ITypeOfObjectsBoundToListBox` is declared.

Comment: `ITypeOfObjectsBoundToListBox` is not a real type. The answerer was using it to represent whatever type of items are in your list. You should replace it with the actual type.