# Win32 API vs Windows Api Set (WIn10), Are Windows Api Sets a DLL wrapper for full win32api?

Tags: windows, winapi

By reading MSDN Doc, i got info about windows api sets, what the relationship between win32api and  Windows Api Sets ?

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-apisets

the old question like this:
[Is the win32 api obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193915/is-the-win32-api-obsolete)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinWin

Comment: @HansPassant MinWin is start with vista, and then , How is it envolution ? ^_^

Comment: It is a pure implementation detail that doesn't affect the way you program at all.  The only reason they had to document it is because it might cause a very mystifying runtime error when you run the program on a minimal OS build that is missing stuff you need.

Answer (score 1):

Think about API sets as namespaces containing individual Win32 APIs.

They are not wrappers, they only do their job while loading a DLL and binding these imported WinAPI functions.

With API sets, MS now able to move implementations of win32 APIs across DLLs, without breaking compatibility.

Comment: So  `Windows API Set`  is sorted subnet of `win32` api ?

Comment: @jamlee It can be regarded as the encapsulation of Win32 API and improve the portability of program.

Comment: Yet, `QtCreator-12-mingw` App was compiled for Windows 10 API-sets **but** does not run on Windows 7 API-sets; **Is there any way to update Windows 7 API-sets???** If not, API-sets are worse than Win32 API.